# tkinter window not working properly with askDirectory

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to have the askDirectory open a floder which the user selects. Once they select this, some other functions will run that will take some time. Instead of putting that here, I added a sleep function to represent this. While this is running, I need another window to show that something is running in the background. I cannot seem to achieve this. This code creates the loading window but never proceeds to the sleep function. If I move the mainloop() or remove it, the sleep function works but the loading window never opens. What am I doing wrong here? Also, ideally I would like this to show an actual loading window instead of static text but I can't even get the window to show properly.

```
import time
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
from tkinter import *

Tk().withdraw()
download_location = askdirectory(title='Find and select the download folder', mustexist=TRUE)

loading_window = Toplevel()
loading_window.geometry = ("500x500")
text = "The device is being reset. This will take a minute."
Label(loading_window, text=text, font=('times', 12)).pack()
loading_window.mainloop()

print("sleeping for 5")
time.sleep(5)

print("The process is complete!")
```

Comment: `.mainloop()` isn't going to return until all windows are closed.  Try `.update_idletasks()` instead, to give the window a chance to update itself, without trying to process any further events.

Comment: I replaced the manloop() with this and the functionality worked but my window did not have the text I placed in it.

Comment: Use threads for long running operations https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-thread-in-tkinter-python/

Comment: @СергейКох Thanks! This might be what I need to achieve the actual loading window instead of static text. I found a solution to my problem right as you posted this. I will post it below while I try threading. I had to remove the mainloop() and create a flag in a while loop. I am not sure why I had to do this.

Comment: @СергейКох threading is requiring me to use mainloop() but when I do this everything runs perfect until the end where the script never closes. Do you know what is causing this or have an example to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest solution. I had to remove the mainloop() completely and use my own while loop which checks for completion via a boolean flag. I am not sure why I couldn't get mainloop() to work. The operation would go through but the program would continue to run in the background.

```
finished_flag = False

def checkProgress():
    loading_window.geometry = ("500x500")
    text = "The device is being reset. This will take a minute."
    Label(loading_window, text=text, font=('times', 12)).pack()
    loading_window.update()
    print("sleeping for 5")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("The process is complete!")

Tk().withdraw()
download_location = askdirectory(title='Find and select the download folder called plantInstaller', mustexist=TRUE)

loading_window = Tk()
while not finished_flag:
    loading_window.after(200, checkProgress())
    finished_flag = True
loading_window.destroy()

print("Finished")
```

Comment: This solution does NOT work with threading, which is needed here. Still unresolved...